# Uncertain if invoking uncertainty principle for wave function is handwaving

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Why doesn't the electron collapse onto the proton in a hydrogen atom?

One explanation seems to be given by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, which follows from the purely physical assertion that the wave function in the position representation is the Fourier transform of the wave function in the momentum (or more precisely the wave number) representation.

A different explanation is obtained by solving (or inspecting) the Schrӧdinger equation.

To what extent are these explanations independent? To what extent is the latter more fundamental? Is the latter explanation more correct, or more complete?

The hydrogen atom is just an example, a more general form of the question would be to what extent it is correct to use the Heisenberg uncertainty principle to answer this kind of questions, as is often done in popular science texts?

Elaborating a bit on what I mean to ask, the fact that the Fourier transform of the  position wave function is the momentum wave function seems to allow us to draw conclusions about the behaviour of a system from this principle alone.

However, when loosely drawing these conclusions, we tend to invoke our classical idea of momentum, whereas the dynamics of the system are really governed by the Schrӧdinger equation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two explanations of non-zero atomic radius](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113830/)

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry, I didn't see the other question, which is certainly related. I do not think it has a complete answer there however, I am especially interested in the question whether the uncertainty principle argument is rigorous and complete (in this kind of questions).

Comment: @doetoe I think your question *is* answered in the link provided by John. It is clear that the uncertainty principle argument only provides an order-of-magnitude figure/ballpark estimate, and can therefore never be really rigorous or complete.

Comment: I think there's an interesting question around the subject of how the Schrodinger equation incorporates the uncertainty principle. Showing this would answer your question in the sense that it would show using the uncertainty principle alone was an approximation to solving the Schrodinger equation. However as it stands this isn't what you're asking.

Comment: @Danu it is clear that the uncertainty principle only gives an estimate, but an estimate can be perfectly rigorous. It also is clear that you cannot derive the full state function from it, but I meant to ask if it could be used to provide a complete answer to a specific question of that form. This would be so if you can derive the answer from only the uncertainty principle, but I have the feeling that you will also need the Schrӧdinger equation (to give a meaning to the momentum wave function in terms of the dynamics, as opposed to referring to the classical meaning).

Comment: All of physics is handwaving... it's just cool that the waving hand can have a precision of one part in a hundred trillion on a good day! As for the Schroedinger equation... there is absolutely nothing fundamental about it. As Mr. Feynman (not even?) jokingly said, it was just a very good guess by Dr. Schroedinger.

Comment: @CuriousOne isn't that exactly what makes a law fundamental in physics, if it can only be guessed, postulated and confirmed by experiment, rather than derived from more fundamental principles?

Comment: @doetoe: I don't think we have found the truly fundamental laws in physics, yet, maybe with exception of thermodynamics, which is really just a consequence of statistics. Having said that, the genius of Schroedinger in "guessing" correctly, what has become a simple model system along the road to the real theory, is undeniable. Have you read Schroedinger's original papers? They are masterpieces of confusion and enlightenment... it still baffles me what the man was thinking.